# mysql: simple sub-query very slow because has 30 million rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a list of posts and comments count for each one.

```
SELECT
    theposts.id, 
    theposts.name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM thecomments WHERE thecomments.post_id = theposts.id) AS comments
FROM theposts
```

The problem is: I have 20k posts and 30 millions comments. The query is extremely slow.

If I use LIMIT 5, it works fine in about 40 seconds. But I need get a full list of 20k posts.

Any tip for how to speed up or debug this query?

The server is running in my Macbook 8gb ram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way that I can think of is to create an index.  You need an index on `thecomments(post_id)`:

```
create index thecomments_postid on thecomments(post_id);
```

This should change the query plan to just an index scan and go pretty quickly.

I also think that this will be faster than using `group by`, which is the other possibility:

```
SELECT theposts.id, theposts.name, COUNT(*) as comment
FROM theposts join
     thecomments
     on thecomments.post_id = theposts.id
GROUP BY theposts.id;
```

Comment: These methods are complimentary.  Use both!

Comment: the index query took 1 minute and the select query took 10 seconds. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

First off is to check that you have indexes where appropriate. That's usually the most common problem.

Another problem is that you may well be running 20,000 sub-queries, depending on how smart your query analysis engine is.

You can achieve the same result in *one* query just by grouping your rows, such as with (depending on your schema):

```
SELECT
    theposts.id           is id, 
    theposts.name         as name,
    count(thecomments.id) as comments
FROM
    theposts, thecomments
WHERE
    thecomments.post_id = theposts.id
GROUP BY thepost.id, theposts.name
```

(that's implicit style join syntax, you could also use explicit `join`).

Comment: You specified the problem well here, but I'm upvoting the one that mentions indexing and has an explicit join.

Comment: thanks for the problem explanation! I tried run the query for 2 minutes and no response. resolved with index. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this with join , you dont need subquery.

```
SELECT
   theposts.id, 
   theposts.name,
   COUNT(*) comments
FROM thecomments 
INNER JOIN theposts ON thecomments.post_id = theposts.id
GROUP BY theposts.id
```

Comment: I tried run the query for 2 minutes and no response. resolved with index. thanks!